# Using CDLJSONPResponseSerializer to hande JSONP in AFNetworking 2.0 in Swift

Tags: swift, jsonp, afnetworking-2

Need help trying to use AFNetworking to access this JSONP data:

http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/AAPL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/

I used the CDLJSONPResponseSerializer found here:

https://github.com/clundie/CDLJSONPResponseSerializer

My code produces "Error: The JSONP response was invalid":

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.responseSerializer = CDLJSONPResponseSerializer()

        manager.GET( "http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/AAPL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/",
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned string is not JSON, it has a function wrapper: "finance_charts_json_callback("  ...  "). That needs too be removed prior to de-serializing the JSON into a dictionary.

Here is "proof of concept" code in Objective-C:
Note 1: The concept is the same in Swift.
Note 2: There is **no** error checking, POC only.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/AAPL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:NULL];

NSData *prefixData1  = [@"(" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange prefixRange1 = [jsonData rangeOfData:prefixData1 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, jsonData.length)];
NSData *suffixData   = [@")" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange suffixRange  = [jsonData rangeOfData:suffixData options:NSDataSearchBackwards range:NSMakeRange(0, jsonData.length)];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(prefixRange1.location+1, jsonData.length - prefixRange1.location - 1 - suffixRange.length);

jsonData = [jsonData subdataWithRange:range];
NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"d: %@", d);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I didnt find an answer to the question I now transformed Zaph's answer to swift code. I integrated it into my class "AbstractAPIService" and here is all the magic I use to handle JSON and JSONP in Swift:

```
func JSONRequest(encodedUrlStr: String, callback: (jsonData: AnyObject?) -> Void, isJSONP: Bool = false){
    let url = NSURL(string: encodedUrlStr)
    if(url != nil){
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(var data, response, error) in
            if (isJSONP){
                if let prefixData = "(".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                    var prefixRange = data.rangeOfData(prefixData, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, data.length))
                    if let suffixData = ")".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                        var suffixRange = data.rangeOfData(suffixData, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, data.length))
                        var jsonRange = NSMakeRange(prefixRange.location + 1, data.length - prefixRange.location - 1 - suffixRange.length)
                        data = data.subdataWithRange(jsonRange)
                    }

                }

            }
            let jsonData:AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
            callback(jsonData: jsonData)
        }
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

You can then easily access the 'jsonData' variable in your custom callback like so:

```
JSONRequest(requestURL, callback: { (jsonData:AnyObject?) -> Void in
        if let data:AnyObject = jsonData  {
            print(data) //prints the json object to the console
            //To access the json data simply reflect its values
            print(data["foo"]) // given json: {"foo": "bar"} would print "bar" 
        }
    })
```

Remember to pass in a boolean as third parameter if you expect JSON**P** data!